# Dem file in .adf format, while .tiff is needed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, convert, dem, geotiff-tiff

I would like to use this standalone tool to get different kind of Dem visualizations (http://iaps.zrc-sazu.si/en/svf#v). I see that the program accept only .tiff DEM.

Now, the DEMs I got are not in that format; rather, I see that the files are .adf

I am wondering if I need to convert the DEM I have into .tiff, and how it can be accomplished (possibly in ArcGIS 10.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.adf is part of the raster [arcinfo binary grid](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#AIG). You can convert it using arcgis (just add to your dataframe then right click to export it. Giving a .tif extension will automatically convert to a tif file. Note that you need to have the directory with your adf files in it.

EDIT :  GDAL also provide this conversion if you prefer open source. The output type is GTiff by default and you can specify other output type by using the -of (output format) option.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, which helped to sort my problem out. Best Regards.

Comment: In GDAL it is not the extension that defines the output format. GTiff is the default